# prove that $v$ is not a Linear combination of $u,w$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,W$ be subspaces of $V$, Let $u,v,w$ $\in V-{0}$

Given that

$u\in U,u\notin W$

$w\in W$

$v\in W$ and ($v$ is not a scalar multiplication of $w$)

prove that $v$ is not a Linear combination of $u,w$

Comment: I assume you made a typo in your question since every vector is always trivially a linear combination of itself.

Comment: Furthermore, you should at least say what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct question is: prove that $\;v\;$ is not a linear combination of $\;u,w\;$. In that case $\;v\;$ and $\;w\;$ are linearly independent by hypothesis. Moreover $\;u\notin W \supseteq Span(v,w)\;.\;$ For that reason $\;u,v,w\;$ are linearly independent and so $\;v\;$ is not a linear combination of $\;u,w\;$